# React-hot-loader is almost working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-hot-loader

I have managed to get the webpack flow working and the browser is getting the hot-updates. But for some reason i can't understand the swaping of modules won't seem to work properly...

This is my index.js:

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

import authenticationMiddleware from './middleware/authentication.js';
import messageMiddleware from './middleware/navigationMessage.js';
import apiMiddleware from './middleware/api.js';

import AppRouter from './router.jsx';

import RootReducer from './reducers/root-reducer.js';

let store = createStore(RootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, apiMiddleware, messageMiddleware, authenticationMiddleware, routerMiddleware(browserHistory)));

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

let rootElement = document.getElementById('app-root');
const hotRender = (CurrentAppRouter) =>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CurrentAppRouter history={history} />
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    rootElement
  );

hotRender(AppRouter);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./router.jsx', () => {
    hotRender(AppRouter);
  });
}

Provider.childContextTypes = {
  store: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

I get this in my console in chrome:

[image: js console]

And yet the html is not updateing, not even when i manualy navigate back and forth does the changes come through, only when i manualy reload the page does my changes appear.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

My dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.20.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.6.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.18.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "mobile-detect": "^1.3.3",
    "raven": "^1.1.1",
    "raven-js": "^3.9.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.6",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-icons": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.23.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.7",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.1"
  }
```

Comment: Which version of react-hot-loader are you using?

Comment: @JoshKelley: Updated my question with my dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm far from being an expert on react-hot-loader, I was able to get it working by following examples [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools/tree/master/examples/todomvc) and [here](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/MigrationGuide.md/#react-hot-loader).

My code looks something like this.

```
import Root from './containers/Root';
// Root has the <Provider><Router>...</Router></Provider> components

render(
  <AppContainer>
    <Root store={store} history={history}/>
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./containers/Root', () => {
    const Root = require('./containers/Root').default;
    render(
      <AppContainer>
        <Root store={store} history={history}/>
      </AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('app')
    );
  });
}
```

From comparison with your code, the biggest difference seems to be that I'm re-`require`ing the root component whenever hot reloading is triggered.  I'm also configuring hot reloading one layer above react-router.

I'm getting the same react-router warning that shows up in your console and am currently simply ignoring it; hot loading of the rest of my application is working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it inspired me to try to minimice the problems.
In the end the problem was me not having react-hot-loader/babel plugin in my .bablerc file.
Took i while to figure that out but now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `module.accept` code to

```
let render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
     <AppContainer>
       <Provider store={store}>
          <CurrentAppRouter history={history} />
       </Provider>
      </AppContainer>,
      rootElement
    )
} 

module.hot.accept('./router.jsx', () =>
  setImmediate(() => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(rootElement)
    render()
  })
)
```

Comment: Tried your example with the only difference that I added a render(); before the module.hot.accept aswell so we get an inital render.
Unfortunatly it did not work. Same result.

Comment: Actually I have another solution - use only `module.hot.accept()`, without any arguments, it can help (I don't actually know in which cases).